# Building one-to-many function from points

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a way to build one-to-many function from points.
$$ x \in \{0 , 1\}$$
$$ y \in [0 , n], n \in N  $$

So, I have points like
$$ (0,1),(0,2),(1,3),(1,4)$$
and I need a function that connects them.

The function accepts $x$ and returns the set $y$.

something like $\sin^{-1}$ does.

Do you know where I should look for such algorithm?

Comment: Call the function $f$. You want $f$ to be a function from the set $\{0,1\}$ to what exactly? And how will $f(0)$ differ from $f(1)$? Do you want $f(0)$ to be the set $\{(0,1),(0,2),\dots,(0,n)\}$ and $f(1)$ to be the set $\{(1,1),(1,2),\dots,(1,n)\}$?

Comment: As @almagest already noted, how are you planning on differentiating between ambiguous inputs.

Comment: exactly as Almagest said. but intead of remembering the sets. I need a function that will calculate the set.